# Calculating Percentages of Multiple Record Groups

Tags: postgresql

Right now I am using this query to calculate the percentage of users who have given their email address, by dividing the count of emails by the count of user opt-ins:

```
SELECT cast(A.NUM as float)/cast(A.DENOM as float) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM (SELECT
(SELECT count(*)
FROM "public"."mv_fundraiser_report"
WHERE [[{{NonProfit}}]]
AND [[{{DateRange}}]]
AND "public"."mv_fundraiser_report"."Email" IS NOT NULL) AS NUM,

(SELECT count(*)
FROM "public"."mv_fundraiser_report"
WHERE "public"."mv_fundraiser_report"."opt-in" = TRUE
AND [[{{NonProfit}}]]
AND [[{{DateRange}}]]) AS DENOM) A
```

This is an example of my data:

```
NonProfit|User Name|Opt-In|Email
NP1.     |Hunter   |TRUE  |hunter@hunter.com
NP2.     |Hunter   |TRUE  |hunter@hunter.com
NP3.     |Hunter   |TRUE  |hunter@hunter.com
NP4.     |Hunter   |TRUE  |hunter@hunter.com
NP1.     |Hunter   |TRUE  |hunter@hunter.com
NP2.     |Hunter   |TRUE  |hunter@hunter.com
NP3.     |Hunter   |TRUE  |hunter@hunter.com
NP4.     |Hunter   |TRUE  |hunter@hunter.com
```

What I would like to do is group these records by NonProfit, and then return multiple rows, each individually calculated based on the NonProfit. This is what my end data set should look like:

```
NonProfit|Email %
NP1.     |57
NP2.     |52
NP3.     |100
NP4.     |31
```

From what I understand, window functions do not allow you to select multiple rows, so how could this outcome be achieved? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
select
  NonProfit,
  sum(case when email is not null then 1 else 0 end) / count(*) * 100 as percentage
from mv_fundraiser_report
where opt_in and ...
group by NonProfit
```

That's assuming you want to divide the number of *opt-in users* with email by the number of opt-in users, which is slightly different from your query above. If not, divide by `sum(case when opt_in then 1 else 0 end)` and drop the opt_in from the where condition.

Comment: Thanks for your help man! I tried out the query and it returns all the the NonProfits but all of the percentages are 0. When I remove the division problem and just return the count, it seems to be returning the correct numbers, and vice versa. Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: Never mind, I just had to cast the results as floats. Thanks a ton!